# How to get proper Tomcat webapps path in all environments?

Tags: java, linux, spring, tomcat

So, there is this API that creates new folders in **tomcat/webapps/rules** and it copies rule files from a master rules folder. If I'm creating a folder **abc**, it'll copy rules from **tomcat/webapps/rules/masterRule** to **tomcat/webapps/rules/abc**

Now, this is what we use in java code to get the path

```
Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("catalina.base") + File.separator + "webapps" + File.separator+ "rules" + File.separator + dc_name);
```

Now this works fine in dev and test environments. But fails in prod. Because the path is **/usr/local/tomcat** but it's empty. We have option to upload rule from UI and when we do that, it creates folder in EFS **/efs-files/tomcat/webapp/rules**

In short,

- dev and test = **/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.22/webapps/rules**
- prod (but empty) = **/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/rules**
- prod (when uploading file from UI) = **/efs-files/tomcat/webapp/rules**

How do I write the java code which will ensure that it's in the right path in all environments?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the wrong path when you're trying to write to a web application's own directory. There are several reasons for this:

- Web applications can be deployed as WAR files, without ever being unzipped to disk - so there simply might be no representation of your application in the file system.
- Proper hardening of production sites typically prohibits writing to that directory anyway - so even if you know where your files are located physically, you *should* not assume that directory to be writable
- One reason for the previous hardening rule is: Recovery. In case of a server failure, it should be 100% clear which backup to restore, what version of your software was deployed etc. And that typically means that the application is completely separated from its data.

So: The right path in all environments is one explicitly configured for being writable, backed up, and not contain potentially executable malware (think of someone uploading JSP files). And that path is outside of Tomcat's `webapps` directory. In fact, it's typically unrelated to Tomcat's installation location - or it's the `temp` directory, in case you don't care about backing these files up.